# How to write a more efficient query to get child categories and paginate

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, performance, pagination

I'm using this code to show only child categories and paginate them, but this is horribly slow `(49 queries in 9,799 seconds.)`.

I know that I'm doing this by using relying built-in Wordpress querying functions and this is not a good practice, but instead, one of the causes that make this so slow...

I couldn't find a better way to do this and I need help to write a more efficient query.

How can this run faster?

```
<?php

$current_cat = get_query_var('cat');
$attributes = array('terms_per_page' => 20, 'taxonomy' => 'category');

// Sanitize and validate our inputs and set variables
$tpp = filter_var( $attributes['terms_per_page'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT );
$taxonomy = filter_var( $attributes['taxonomy'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

// Make sure our taxonomy exists to avoid unnecessary work
if ( !taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) )
return false;

// Our taxonomy exists, lets continue. Now, get the terms count to calculate pagination.
$term_count = count( get_terms('category',array('hide_empty'=>'1','child_of' => $current_cat) ) );

// We have terms, now calculate pagination
$max_num_pages = ceil( $term_count / $tpp );
// Get current page number. Take static front pages into account as well
if ( get_query_var('paged')){
$paged = get_query_var('paged');
} elseif ( get_query_var('page')) {
$paged = get_query_var( 'page' );
} else {
$paged = 1;
}
// Calculate term offset
$offset = ( ( $paged - 1 ) * $tpp );

// We can now get our terms and paginate it
$args = array(
'number'     => $tpp, // Amount of terms to return
'offset'     => $offset, // The amount to offset the list by for pagination
'child_of'   => $current_cat,
'orderby'    => 'name', 
'order'      => 'ASC', 
'hide_empty' => '1',
);
// Set our variable to hold our string
$output = '';
$wpbtags = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );

if ( ! empty($wpbtags)) {
foreach ($wpbtags as $category) { 

//first get the current category ID
$cat_prefix = "category_";
$cat_id = $category->term_id;
//then i get the data from the database
$join_cat = $cat_prefix . $cat_id;
$cat_data = get_option($join_cat);?>

<a href="<?php echo get_category_link($category->term_id); ?>"     onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'ClickNav', 'cats', 'Cat - <?php echo $category-    >cat_name; ?>');">
<div class="one_fourth<?php echo ( ++$counter == 4 )?' last_column':''; ?> home-colour" title="<?php echo $category->name; ?>">

<?php if (!empty($cat_data['cat_img_url'])) : ?>
<h2 style="text-align:center"> <?php echo $category->name; ?> </h2>
<img class="res_img" src="<?php echo $cat_data['cat_img_url'] ;?>" alt="<?php echo $category->cat_name; ?>" width="310" height="209" />

<?php elseif (empty($cat_data['cat_img_url'])) :?>
<h2 style="text-align:center"> <?php echo $category->name; ?> </h2>
<img class="res_img" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/subcat-img-na.png" alt="Posts - <?php echo $category->cat_name; ?>"/>

<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div><!-- eof cat div --> </a>

<?php } ?>   

<?php /* COUNTS FOUR ADDS LAST COLUMN */ if ( $counter == 4 ) : ?>
<div class='clear'> </div>
<?php $counter = 0; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

<div class='clear'> </div>

<?php echo '<div class="wp-pagenavi" style="text-align:center">';
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
echo paginate_links( array(
'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
'format' => '?paged=%#%',
'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
'total' => $max_num_pages = (ceil( $term_count / $tpp))
) );

echo '</div>';
?>   

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php  /* IF THERE'S NOTHING TO SHOW */ } else {?>

// Show something if there is no posts here

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: See my [_blog on pagination_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination)

Comment: @RickJames do you think that the slowness problem is on the pagination?

Comment: Please provide the SQL statement(s) involved.